# Stacked barchart, coloring individual cells

Tags: r, bar-chart, stacked

I am trying to create a stacked barchart, but with individual cells colored based on a separate value. This is an example data set that I'm using:

```
count sample label
50      A    DD
20      A    BB
20      A    CC
10      A    AA
20      B    JJ
20      B    LL
10      B    BB
15      B    CC
30      B    AA
5       B    HH
```

I'm using the following code to create the plot and color the cells that I want colored, but it colors the wrong cells. I'm not sure why though:

```
Library(lattice)
data$rank <- rank(data$count)
colVec <- rep("white", nrow(data))
colVec[data$label == "AA"] <- "red"
barchart(count ~ sample, groups = as.factor(rank), stack = TRUE, data = data, 
    as.table = TRUE, col = colVec, ylab = "Counts")
```

In this example, I want the top bar in sample B and last bar in sample A colored red (the cells with label AA), but it ends up coloring 5 completely different cells.

The real data set I'm looking to use this code with has thousands of sample entries, so I can't use a manual approach.

Answer (score 0):

The groups portion defines how the stacked portions of the barchart are named and sorted.  Therefore you need to create a new grouping vector, that has unique names for each box and is sorted in the order you want.  Then you can just set the color vector appropriately.

```
data$label2 <- paste(data$label, data$sample)
data$label2 <- reorder(data$label2, data$rank)
colVec = rep("white", length(levels(data$label2)))
colVec[grepl('AA', levels(data$label2))] = "red"
barchart(count ~ sample, groups = label2, stack = TRUE, data = data, as.table = TRUE, ylab = "Counts", col=colVec)
```

Comment: Thanks, but now the bars are out of order. Sorry, I should have specified that I need the largest cells at the top of each bar and then descending to the smallest.

Comment: Fixed to preserve the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You want a "group" for each data point, ordered by count. You'll just need to reorder your color vector to the same order, done with indexing here.

```
g <- order(data$count)
colVec <- ifelse(data$label=="AA","red","white")[g]
barchart(count ~ sample, groups = factor(1:10,levels=g), 
  stack = TRUE, data = data, col=colVec)
```